# How create change beackround by uesrs?

Tags: flutter, dart

Good afternoon everyone.
Please help me to solve the issue.
I need to make it so that the user can change the background on their own, based on the options I suggested. The background will change only on one screen and for the background I decided to choose images.
That is, going to the quote screen, for example, the user can click on the button and a list of available pictures for changing the background will appear for him to choose from.
I've been looking for how to implement such an idea for the third day already and I can't find anything, please help!

Comment: could include what have you done so far?

Comment: Do want to change background of screen by getting values from the user?

Comment: @mesh, yes! I want to offer the user several pictures to choose from (stored locally) and give him the opportunity to choose a background from them for the screen on which quotes will be placed

Comment: Hmm. Actually I don't understand what you want to do. But if I understand correct. There are many way to do this. If I were you I would use riverpod for this concept. Because it is a state managment package.  And I would use "shared refrences" to save the background type as a variable on my local storage.